# SpcalenderView Javascript on Mouse hower

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

I have one issue with spcalendarview. I just wanted to show spcalender item to the contain editor web part from the link [here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/jquery-for-everyone-preview-pane-for-calendar-view.aspx)

but i wanted to my custom page into the contain editor web part
so how to get hower event of spcalender item event

Comment: Are you asking how to handle the mouse hovering over an item in the calendar view?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your custom page instead of DispForm.aspx?ID=x then you need to pass your custom page url to the jLoadMe function, so in line 14 of the sample code on the link you posted, replace

```
var t = $(e).attr("href");
```

with

```
var t = "MyCustomPageUrl.htm"
```